# Dynamics CRM 2016- Limit user accessing Account record before closing the existing opened record

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm seeking for the solution or suggestion, to find out that did this function is able to work in CRM 2016.

"User A" is opening an (account record form A), in the moment the "User A" is trying to open the another (account record form B) while the previous account record form still haven't close.

Here the requirement from my client.

The (account record form B) is unable to open while there is existing (account record form A) is opened up. 
That means the User is only can open the Account record form once at a same time.

I am appreciate if anyone can leave a comment.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible not only in Dynamics CRM, but also in any Web Application or website out there. This is technically not possible, because user can always open a different browser or browser in private mode and you will not be able to control that (unless you deploy some malware software on all users computer, but this is clearily not a Dynamics CRM customizations thing)

Answer (score 1):

Pawel makes a good point about web apps in general.

Because we have the plugin model and JavaScript in CRM, there is a hypothetical possibility of building something for this - though it pushes the boundaries of abuse of the CRM extension model.

The idea would be something like this:

1. Create an external table to maintain a list of open Account forms by user.
2. Register a plugin on the retrieve message of the Account. When the user retrieves an account, populate an entry into the table.
3. If the user attempts to retrieve another Account, check the table. If they have an open Account form, prevent the retrieve.
4. Create JavaScript on the Account form to remove the entry in the external table when the user closes the Account form.

If this could even work, it would be a complex, fragile solution that would likely also harm performance.

Unless you want to share the reason why you want only one Account open at a time so we can discuss alternative options, I'd recommend letting this one go.